# Bad access on NSString length

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

with

```
NSString *responseData = [request responseString];
```

I get a string like `(10)`.

Now I want to remove the brackets to get just the number. So I first wanted to get the length of the string

```
NSLog(@"%@",[responseData length]);
```

But I get a `Thread 1: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD:ACCESS"`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSString::length` returns an unsigned integer. So, try -

```
NSLog(@"%i",[responseData length]); // format specifier is %i and not %@
                                    // Even better if %u is used.
```

[NSLog format specifiers](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSLog)